# Por que estou tendo acesso a esse ponteiro mesmo depois de dar free()?

Tags: c, ponteiro, gerenciamento-de-memória

Tenho este programa e teoricamente não era para perder o endereço de new depois de dar o free tornando o mesmo inacessível ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int numTeste;
}strPt;


int main (){
    strPt * new;
    new = (strPt*) malloc(sizeof(strPt));
    new->numTeste = 4;
    printf("Endereço new: %p\n",new);
    printf("Numero na struct: %d\n",new->numTeste);
    free(new);
    printf("Endereço new: %p\n",new);
    printf("Numero na struct: %d\n",new->numTeste);
    return 0;
}
```

O resultado obtido foi esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu tento acessar o `new->numTeste`, não deveria dar erro ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A função `free()` não impede o acesso a nenhum endereço. Qualquer tentativa de acesso a um endereço será bem sucedida (tudo bem, tem uma exceções de proteção, mas não vem ao caso para esse exemplo).

C é uma linguagem que não proíbe você acessar dados indesejáveis. Se você quer acessar um endereço ele será acessado, não importa se tem o que você quer ou não, é responsabilidade sua garantir que o acesso é adequado e produz o resultado pretendido.

`free()` não apaga dado algum, ele permanece lá até que alguma operação escreva por cima dele. E o endereço continuará acessível mesmo depois disso, só que agora tem um dado que não é o mesmo. Nada te informa que está errado, se não tomar cuidado causará problemas, potencialmente sérios. Sem falar na segurança falha.

A única coisa que a função faz é indicar para o gerenciador de memória utilizado que aquele endereço pode ser utilizado para outra coisa quando necessitar.

Assim, ao contrário do que deve estar imaginando, a função `malloc()` não cria um ponteiro, apenas reserva um espaço na memória e devolve um ponteiro para esse endereço. Este ponteiro é só um endereço, ele não tem nada de especial. É como ter 10 reais na carteira. São apenas 10 reais, não são 10 reais que só podem ser usados para pagar um sanduba na padaria do seu Manuel.

Se quer garantias procure uma linguagem com gerenciamento de memória automático, ou pelo menos seguro, não é o caso de C que é uma linguagem poderosa, rápida e flexível, não segura. A segurança é dada por você.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Só gostaria de saber o por que disso pois precisava que o ponteiro liberado fosse igual a NULL (coisa que eu pensava que a função `free()` fazia), mas mesmo depois de liberar a memória, quer dizer que posso setar o ponteiro `new` para NULL que dará certo ?

Comment: Sim dará, e poderá continuar acessando o ponteiro, só que não mais poderá acessar o objeto, se tentar dará erro.